# How to pass variable in javascript for query in php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to use the value from input file hidden when I am doing click on href.

```
<a href="#" onclick="invoice_open(<?php echo $counter?>);">confirm</a>

function invoice_open(i){
    var x = document.getElementById("inv"+i).value;
    alert(x);

    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
```

I already success to get the value from input type hidden (var x), but I don't know how to pass x value to php ex. $result = x.

I want to use $result for display data from my database. Please help. Thank you

Comment: have you tried or searched for any resource?

Comment: I already search and the result are it's impossible to pass value from javascript to php, except using ajax. but I dont know how to write it in ajax. :(

Answer (score 0):

since you already get the values using `<?php echo $counter?>` then you can do

```
var counter = '<?php echo $counter?>'
```

in javascript.  And typical AJAX approach would be like the following..

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php&counter=' + counter,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        complete: function() {

        },          
        success: function(json) {
            // do something with DOM, redirect ... etc
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // handles exception
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Shih-Min Lee, but I still can't understand it. $counter only contain number, because there are maybe more than 1 input type hidden for item list in my shopping cart. var x = document.getElementById("inv"+i).value will result the invoice no based on the a href that user click

Comment: this require jquery though.

Comment: ya you can use jquery to read/write shopping cart info in javascript (possible an array object) and pass those info into your API route params. and the request url will be 'index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3' something like this